# Android development for Samsung tab2 tablet

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Is it possible to develop android applications in Samsung tab 2 tablet using Eclipse? 
Does it require any driver installation?

Comment: Why not? You must intall standart dev's soft...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of Course You Can!
you have to install standard android developpement tools (SDK,ADT) ad eclipse (Juno latest release). Download SDK from this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), refer also to this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) to learn how to intall it and finally install the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

1. Install the correct device driver from Samsung onto your
   workstation, I advice you to install [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) that will be
   enough to recognize your Android Tablet, it contains the necessary
   drivers to work with your Android Sambung tablet.
2. Pick the correct API level for your project, i.e. HoneyComb
3. Turn on "**USB debugging**" on your mobile device *Settings -->
   Applications --> Development --> "USB Debugging"*
4. Connect your Tablet via USB, it should be visible in Eclipse now
   (DDMS perspective), you can run your apps on your tablet now.

Comment: To enable developer mode you have to go to "About the device" in settings and tap 7 times over the compilation number section!

Answer (score 1):

No Driver required to install in Apple Mac. It's directly detect in Eclipse.

Comment: I am using Windows XP. From where can I get the required drivers for samsung tab 2

Comment: Yes Definitely. you have install.