# Eclipse is not recognizing my Android tablet

Tags: android, eclipse

I think I have done everything right but I cannot get Eclipse to recognize my plugged in running Samsung Tab-2.  Below is what I have done.  What have I done wrong?

1) I have instelled USB drivers and can move files from the tablet to the Windows XP computer.

2) I have enabled USB debugging on the phone

3) I have been debugging on a virtual device then sending the apd files over email to my tablet and phone.  That works fine.  Obviously, I have enabled that on the phone.

4) I set up Eclipse to always ask what device to debug on.

5) I plugged the tablet into the USB slot and it is recognized by Windows.

6) I read the instructions [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

7) I click debug and am faced with a blank list of devices under "Choosing a running Android Device".  My tablet does not show up.

8) I find myself at wit's end (adventure reference).

9) I ask for help on Stackoverflow.

Comment: what is the output of `adb devices` ?

Comment: @user827992 It is blank.  All it says is List of devices attached

Comment: so it's not about Eclipse, you don't have any device that is actually connected. Try re-installing the drivers and change the USB port, also remember that Windows is not the best platform for Android, Google suggest to use Ubuntu 64 bit as main platform.

Comment: @user827992 I must say that your comment that Windows is not the best platform is what got me to try the reboot.  Thanks for your help.  Although I should have thought of it myself, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338092/828728) answer. An identical issue was accepted at that post.

Hope it works to you!

Answer (score 1):

Try a different MicroUSB cable, I have seen this affect the device showing up in Eclipse, even if the cable is working fine for everything else (even transferring files to/from that specific device).

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works you can use adb over wifi by calling : adb connect "your ip adress". I am assuming the Tab runns Android ICS. You can enable Adb over wifi right under the USB debugging- menu point.

Comment: No wifi on my desktop.  I found the answer and will enter it.

Answer (score 0):

How many times have I called tech support and had them tell me to reboot windows?  Well, the solution was to reboot windows.  Nowhere in any of the installation instructions did I skip a step of rebooting but just thought I should try that.

Comment: Hahaha well some times its might easier than you think.